# Nested dynamic for loops in Java

Tags: java, dynamic, nested-loops

I am looking for some help with respect to building dynamic nested loops in Java. I have a situation where in i have to calculate a value in each loop and finally use all these values to calculate the final formula in the innermost loop.

```
    for(float i = -100;i <= 100;i = i+50){
  newb1= b1*((100-i)/100);
  for(float j = -100;j <= 100;j = j+50){
    newb2= b2*((100-j)/100);
    for(float k = -100;k<=100;k=k+50){
      newb3= b3*((100-k)/100);
      for(float l = -100;l<=100;l=l+50){
       newb4 = b4*((100-l)/100);
       for(float m = -100;m<=100;m=m+50){
        newb5= b5*((100-m)/100);
         for(float n = -100;n<=100;n=n+50){
          newb6 = b6*((100-n)/100);
          calcFormula= (float) ((-9.50505103 ) + newb1* (0.0001315718 )+newb2* (0.0001133448)+ newb3* (-0.000006436305)+ newb4* (0.0001379046)+ newb5* (0.0002519799) + newb6* (0.0001530821));
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

But i need to have these nested loops dynamically depending on the number of b's passed. Here in the above code, i have hardcoded till b6, but this has to be achieved dynamically. **Also all the for loops have to run from same start index to same end index with equal increments (all these variables are also configurable, like startIndex, endIndex and increment)**. How do i achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Recursion would work here; with reasonable simplicity if the b's were an array.

Comment: Why are you using `float` for integers? It works, but it's horrible.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Could you please provide a sample as i am new to this?

Comment: Probably so expressions like `((100-i)/100)` evaluate in floating point. There are better ways though: use an `int` then change to  `((100.0-i)/100)`

Comment: @sraf: You ought to figure it out yourself. Good luck!